# Memory Leak from NSXMLParser

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, cocos2d-iphone, nsxmlparser

im running cocos2d with levelSVG, a SVG Parsing system from Sapus Media.
I'm using the parse system, which works as predicted, but im having a few problems with memory leaks associated with the NSXMLParser.
The Memory Leaks give a consistent drop in fps over a timespan of 5 minutes and render the application useless at 12fps at the end of this timeframe.
I have removed all my particlesystems and other potentially leaky objects and the leak still exists..

**Running the Memory Leak Tool:**
*3 Leaking Objects Detected:*
GeneralBlock-512
GeneralBlock-512
NSConcreteMapTable

They link to:

*

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];  

        [parser setDelegate:self];
        [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
        [parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
        [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
        [parser parse];

        NSError *parseError = [parser parserError];
        if(parseError) {
            SVGLOG(@"Error parsing SVG file: %@", parseError);
        }

        [parser release];
```

As you can see, the object is released after the parsing has been completed.

Driving me bonkers, does anyone know whats happening?

Comment: what about the xml parsing methods itself, may be the leak comes from there.

Comment: Did you run Leaks on the Simulator or a device?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a bit of research I found a bug in the NSXMLParser when using the URL method as described above.

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url]
```

By changing this to:

```
NSData *xml = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];            
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xml];
```

This fixed the memory leak issue but still didnt account for the consistent drop of fps over the timeframe.
I then found that my allocations of memory for a particular class, CCFollow was consistently increasing overtime on the memory-leak tool.

I then checked the code and I was running an infinite CCAction - CCFollow, within a repeating tick update method. This was the source of the memory drain.
Removing it from the tick update method and moving it to an initialisation method fixed this problem.